# Autostart program on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, autostart

How can I automatically start my program when windows mobile is started?

(The program should be aware of being started by autostart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/WiMoAutostart.aspx

Comment: Be aware that if this is a CF app, you can't use the LaunchXX reg keys directly.  See this: http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx

Comment: I used the SHCreateShortcut function to put my app into the startup folder. Works like charm, thanks.